# How to add <tag> to php string

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm kinda new to PHP and I'm trying to add a  tag within a PHP variable.

This is what I have, and it's not working.

```
$linkText .= "<span>" . ( 'Reply', $this->_slug ) . "</span>";
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks :)

UPDATE:

This is the complete working code:

```
$linkText = __( 'Reply', $this->_slug );
$linkAttrs['href'] = "http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to={$tweet->id_str}";
$linkAttrs['class'] = 'in-reply-to';
$linkAttrs['title'] = $linkText;
$widgetContent .= $this->_buildLink( $linkText, $linkAttrs );
```

What I'm trying to do here is to add a  tag around $linkText so that I get a result like

```
<a href="#"><span>Title</span></a>
```

Comment: is it possible the comma between 'Reply' and this->_slug needs to be a dot?

Comment: @StephanCelis No. __() is a Wordpress function that registers a string for translation and returns the result if one is found (vs _e(), which echos the result). [More information here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$linkText .= '<span>Reply ' . $this->_slug . '</span>';
```

There's no need for brackets, you can basically concatenate (join) strings and variables using `.`. I have merged the 'Reply' into the span tag as they are both strings, only the PHP variable `$this->_slug` and and the strings need separating with `.`

[Here is the manual page for strings in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Based on your update, and checking out the [twitter plugin source code](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/twitter-widget-pro/trunk/wp-twitter-widget.php), here is the code I think you need:

```
$linkText = '<span>' . __( 'Reply', $this->_slug ) . '</span>';
$linkAttrs['href'] = "http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to={$tweet->id_str}";
$linkAttrs['class'] = 'in-reply-to';
$linkAttrs['title'] = $linkText;
$widgetContent .= $this->_buildLink( $linkText, $linkAttrs, true );
```

I've also passed a `true` parameter to the `buildLink()` which prevents the `<span>` tag from being escaped.

Comment: Hi @Dunhamzzz This did not work for me... It returns `<span>Reply twitter-widget-pro</span>`

Comment: In that case `$this->_slug` is not the variable you need or you are editing in the wrong place!

Comment: Thnx! Change the top line to `$linkText = '<span></span>' . __( 'Reply', $this->_slug );` to get it the way I needed it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to concatenate parenthesis without putting it between a pair of quotes and you should use dots instead of commas.

```
$linkText .= "<span>(Reply " . $this->_slug . ")</span>";
```

P.S. Remove the paranthesises if you think I got you wrong and you don't need them :)

Comment: Just so you realize, __() is actually a wordpress function that registers text for translation. He wasn't trying to actually wrap his text with parentheses. [Read more about it here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure if i get it right, but if $this->_slug is an function you have to call it like this:

```
$linkText .= "<span>" . $this->_slug('Reply') . "</span>";
```